# Cannot start IntelliJ IDEA on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, intellij

I have a problem launching IntelliJ IDEA on **L**ubuntu 18.04. When I run idea.sh, I get this warning in console:

```
(java:3337): dbind-WARNING **: 14:16:37.242: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

Then an IntelliJ startup window opens (with the progress bar), and after that a window with the following text opens:

```
Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager'
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:216)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$initApplication$0(IdeaApplication.java:75)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager'
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:257)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:506)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:453)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:91)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:391)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:209)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel
at com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.IdeaLaf.initIdeaDefaults(IdeaLaf.java:81)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.IdeaLaf.initComponentDefaults(IdeaLaf.java:28)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:150)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1560)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.darcula.DarculaLaf.getDefaults(DarculaLaf.java:95)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:587)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.LafManagerImpl.setCurrentLookAndFeel(LafManagerImpl.java:395)
at com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.LafManagerImpl.initComponent(LafManagerImpl.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:488)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:224)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 37 more
```

I have already reported the problem to that url, but I got no answer (at least for now).
What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

**UPD:** While researching this issue I stubled upon [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000393879-IntelliJ-not-starting-Ubuntu-18-04?input_string=Cannot_run_IntelliJ_IDEA_on_Lubuntu_18.04), which describes the similar problem. 
People there advise to use IDEA's bundled JRE instaed of other versions. But now I have a different problem - I don't know how to change it. I've read [the instruction](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under), but it says I need to edit the `/home/<username>/.<product>/<product>.jdk` file. I don't have such a file and such a directory. The instruction also suggests to edit `/bin/idea.sh`, but I don't know what exactly to edit there. What should I edit?

Comment: Are you using an unsupported Java version?  Seems like 9 and up are not supported.

Comment: I use Java 11 or something like that

Comment: Did you use ls -al so you can see the .<product> folder? I mean when you do ls make sure you include the -a option so you can see the hidden folders (those with starting with "."

Comment: I just used it and i saw the folder. But I cannot open it with cd command (I'm new to Linux, so...)

Comment: Ok, so I opened the directory, but there is no product.jdk file

Comment: What is in the directory? should be intellij.jdk or something like that.

Comment: This is what `ls -a` shows me there: `.  ..  config  system`

Comment: Not sure if it does not have the path it is supposed to have.

Comment: Is there a way to change it in `/bin/idea.sh` like I've been told in the instruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've fixed the problem by installing Oracle's Java 8 and setting it as a default. Previously I had OpenJDK Java 11.