# How to change IntelliJ IDEA's JRE

Tags: lubuntu, intellij, jre

I have [a problem with launching IntelliJ IDEA on **L**ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068810/cannot-start-intellij-idea-on-lubuntu-18-04). While researching this issue I stubled upon [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000393879-IntelliJ-not-starting-Ubuntu-18-04?input_string=Cannot_run_IntelliJ_IDEA_on_Lubuntu_18.04), which describes the similar problem. 
People there advise to use IDEA's bundled JRE instaed of other versions. But  I don't know how to change it. I've read [the instruction](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under), but it says I need to edit the `/home/<username>/.<product>/<product>.jdk` file. I don't have such a file. The instruction also suggests to edit `/bin/idea.sh`, but I don't know what exactly to edit there. What should I edit?

Comment: This ought to be done from the ide let me see if I can confirm that...

Comment: The problem is I can't run the IDE itself. So I have to change it somewhere in files.

Comment: Ok, but it should first run with your own jdk in any case the place to change that is in the `idea.sh` don.t have a copy would have looked for the right spot. Ok I thin k I have a copy will check and revert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you currently use OpenJDK to run your IDE, you have to install Oracle Java JDK manually, here the command to use :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Once the proprietary version is installed, you can switch system wide the java version with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And choose the appropriate java version by typing selection number (3 in my case).

```
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      automatic mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64/jre/bin/java       318       manual mode
```

Comment: It says that "the package is not available, but mentioned in the dependencies of an other package. It can mean that the package is lacking, outdated or not available from sources specified in sources.list"

Comment: Maybe the text of an error is not 100% accurate, because I translated it from another language

Comment: Strange as the package is available for Bionic 18.04 https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java?field.series_filter=bionic Does the ppa adding was worked?

Comment: Ok, so your answer actually helped me to solve the problem, I just used an another instruction to install Oracle Java 8. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have this process as I can update it for other people that have the issue issue? Happy to see your problem is now solved.

Comment: I used this instruction: https://medium.com/coderscorner/installing-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-16-10-845507b13343